# Rules or Laws to guide sectioning and sub-sectioning

Tags: writing

Regardless of the field or subject, is there a website or organization that has rules on how to section and sub-section a document? I have a document on which I have randomly chosen a layout.

project document outline:

```
1. Define Goals to stakeholders
2. Product/ Objective/ Expectations
3. Scope
4. Time Frame with phases and processes
5. Project Budget
6. Risk and Benefits
7. Team members and organizational chart w/ roles and responsibilities matrix
8. Rules of Communication
9. extra docs include:
    a. action and issue tracker
    b. project charter
    c. project organization
    d. project roles and responsibilities
    e. project plan
    f. project budget breakdown
    g. stakeholder matrix
    h. risk log
    i. project communication plan
    j. scope statement/requirement specification
    k. change request tracker
    l. design document
    m. possible obstacles & problems

10. Full visualization of organization and process.
```

This layout is completely a guess, and I am wondering if there is a guide to how to section and subsection, some law or rule to do sectioning or sub-sectioning the proper way that anyone from any field can follow

Comment: This question appears to be about a business document, not an academic document.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist is there any stack exchange for business?

Comment: Or [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). They deal with technical writing. Please check their guideline and help center.

Comment: You asked a question [How to move back to main section after finishing a sub-section](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/23561/31266) on Writing SE in June, 2016. You forgot about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the are such organisations and rules.

In fact, there are various standards for formatting documents, including sectioning. See e.g. the APA 6th or 7th edition, or the Chicago Manual of Style; these are widely used.

If you want to publish in a formal outlet, most likely you'll have to apply whichever standard the outlet requires, which could be a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are no laws on such things. In general the layout depends on the material and the audience.

But it looks like you are writing something as part of a proposal, maybe for a research grant. In that case, the recipient might have requirements for what to include in the application. You need to cover all of those things, of course. And it is often best to include them in your application in the order of the requirements listed. This makes it easier for the reader, who has some power to accept or reject, to quickly check that you have all of the needed elements.

But as a general outline, what you have seems to be reasonable.  As a "working document" is is fine. Tailor it to the requirements of the audience, however.